# Showing difference of PD matrices is PD

Tags: matrices

I have a variance matrix,

$$
D =
\begin{bmatrix}
D_{11} & D_{12} \\ 
D_{21} & D_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Each $D$ is invertible, finite, symmetric, p.d. $n \times n$ and invertible. From symmetry, $D_{12} = D_{21}$.

I wish to show that:

$$(D_{22} - D_{12}D_{11}^{-1}D_{21})$$

and

$$(D_{22} - D_{12}D_{11}^{-1}D_{21})^{-1}$$

are p.d.

I do know that $D_{12}D_{11}^{-1}D_{21}$ is p.s.d.

Doing this will help me complete a proof, but it is possible that this difference is actually not p.d.

Comment: Feel free to check again, but I believe this is not idempotent.

Comment: And this matrix is symmetric.

Comment: It makes no sense to say that "each $D$ is finite, symmetric and positive definite". It is sufficient to just assume $D$ is symmetric and positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

$$D^{-1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
D^{11} & D^{12} \\
D^{21} & D^{22} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

By solving $DD^{-1} = I$ for $D^{-1}$ in terms of $D_{11},D_{12},D_{21},D_{22}$, you will find that:

$$D^{22} = (D_{22}-D_{12}D_{11}^{-1}D_{21})^{-1}$$

Since $D$ is symmetric, invertable, and p.d., so is $D^{-1}$.

Because $D^{-1}$ is p.d. D^{22} must be p.d. because it is part of the diagonal.

Thus, $E$ is p.d.